# New / Merged / Deleted branches not updating

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, version-control, branching-and-merging

So at my previous role, whenever someone created a branch in 'develop' I could refresh/ pull and the branch would appear in my VSC Source control. If a branch was deleted on GitHub, the branch also deleted (disappeared) in VSC. In this new repo, we work off of main and branches, more as a place to store code, rather than updating a website.

As you can see below, I deleted (on GitHub) these branches after the PR's were merged. They don't automatically disappear.

[image]

Furthermore, If someone else makes a branch from main, it will not appear in my list (as mine would not in theirs). Before this would be automatic. This is quite annoying as today for example, I made a branch in prep for another dev, and wanted them to just refresh 'branches' and switch to it.

I have tried git fetch, git remote update origin, prunes etc - nothing seems to work but manual updates and cloning branches from github.

Advice is really appreciated. Is it something to do with the repo setup?

Edit: New clone of the repo: branches don't show. I ran a git fetch and fetch --all but as you can see, nothing happened.

[image]

[image]

It might also be worth mentioning, if I open the repo on GitHub Desktop, I can see the branches, I can switch to the branch > open in VSC and then the branch is now displaying, allowing me to swap between main and said branch as expected.

Below is a screenshot of git branch --all
[image]

Comment: _"They don't automatically disappear"_ why would they? A remote repo has no effect on the local one.

Comment: @evolutionxbox At my last job, they would do so. Furthermore, shouldn't git remote prune origin or other such commands remove these branches for me?

Comment: `git fetch` will get you new branches from the remote. `git fetch --prune` will also delete your copy of remote branches that have since been deleted on the remote. Your question implies you tried both of these already and it didn't help. In that case a possible explanation is that you and the person you're testing with aren't using the same remote repo.

Comment: @TTT Correct, I have tried fetch, also I have tried each of the options built into vsc, rather than the terminal, this didn't help. How might the remote repo be different, if we are all cloning from the same location on github?

Comment: Based on your edit I wonder if you're looking at just local branches? When you clone you'll only have one local branch. All other branches are remote tracking branches. When you fetch you are updating those remote tracking branches. Type `git branch --all` to see both local and remotes.

Comment: @TTT I have added a screenshot of the git branch --all

Comment: @DecisiveDevelopment OK, and are you not seeing a specific branch that you are expecting to see?

Comment: @TTT I would expect git branch --all would pull all branches onto my local right? So that I might swap between them?

Comment: `git branch --all` simply lists all your local branches and also the remote tracking branches you have fetched. If you want to do something with one of those remote branches locally, just check it out. For example: `git switch quadient-dcs-awareness-lp` (or if you're using an older version of Git, `git checkout quadient-dcs-awareness-lp`) will checkout the branch listed as `remotes/origin/quadient-dcs-awareness-lp`. Note you don't need all the remote branches checked out. There really isn't much benefit to checking out a branch locally before you need to use it.

Comment: @TTT I see, so this all appears to be working as intended? If I want to checkout to a branch to my local, I can find it and load it from the remote. How about removing deleted branches, must I do that manually also?

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think yes, it's working as intended. I added an answer that I believe will clear it all up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, I think we've determined that things are working as expected, and the question arose due to a slight misunderstanding of the differences between local branches, and remote tracking branches.

There are many ways to conceptualize this, but I like to think of branches being in 1 of 3 buckets:

1. **Remote branches:** branches that are on the remote repository *now*.
2. **Remote Tracking branches:** your copy of #1 as of the last time you fetched (or pulled which includes a fetch, or cloned if you've never pulled or fetched since then).
3. **Local branches:** branches that you have checked out locally and haven't deleted.

From your point of view, your repo on your machine is made up of buckets 2 and 3. Your file system as you see it is represented by the commit you have checked out *now*, which may be pointed to by one of your local branches, and if not, you are in "detached" mode.

When you clone a repository, you get a copy of the repo as it is at that moment. All of the branches that are on the server you cloned from (#1) are copied into your repo and stored as *remote tracking branches* (#2) These branches are prefixed by your remote name, typically `origin`. Also, when you clone, the default branch will be checked out as your only local branch (in your case the default branch is `main`) and is in bucket #3. You can view your branches with the commands:

```
git branch # view only your local branches
git branch -r # view only your remote tracking branches
git branch --all # view both your local and remote tracking branches
```

After a clone, if you use the command `git branch --all` you should see exactly one local branch, and all of the remote tracking branches that the repo has. Note that branches are simply pointers to a commit, and at that moment your local `main` will point to the same commit as `origin/main`.

Anytime you checkout an existing remote tracking branch for the first time, you create a new local branch pointer to that same commit. If you use the same name as an existing remote tracking branch but without the `origin` prefix, it will assume that's what you meant and track it for you. Otherwise you can create a new branch of any name you'd like, and point it to any commit you'd like.

So in the context of your question, here's what's happening:

1. When you `git fetch` you connect to the remote server, and copy the latest branches from bucket 1 to bucket 2. This brings in new remote tracking branch *names*, and also updates existing ones that have moved to a different commit.
2. When you `git fetch --prune` you do the same as number 1, but you also delete any remote tracking branches in your bucket #2 that have since been deleted in bucket #1.
3. Nothing deletes any of your local branches in bucket #3, except for you.

**Side Note:** I think another source of confusion is that you are using both GitHub Desktop and VS Code and they display "branches" differently. GitHub Desktop lumps the branches in buckets #2 and #3 into the same list of branches (essentially `git branch --all`). VS Code on the other hand, separates the views, and puts local branches (bucket #3 using `git branch`) under "branches", and remote tracking branches (bucket #2 using `git branch -r`) under "remotes". This explains why you couldn't find *all* the branches in VS Code.

Comment: Thank you for your insight my friend, it certainly has cleared things up for me. Potentially my last role has some scripts running or such to do these things, unbenounced to me. I will take some time to study the branch, remote and origin concept some more off the back of this discussion. Thanks again, really appreciate your patience here.

Comment: @DecisiveDevelopment btw, I hadn't used GH desktop before today but I just downloaded it and witnessed what you saw. I added a side note which you may find helpful too. ;)

Comment: Ah yeah, I find the desktop app to just work so well, although in the spirit of learning, I try to use it as a last resort currently. It always pays to understand the hows and whys, before just doing the easy stuff :) but if you have not used it before, I hope I have opened pandoras box for you! It is a great, great tool.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you previously had automatic fetching settings enabled, but they are now disabled somehow.  Check on the following settings:

- `git.autofetch`
- `git.autofetchPeriod`

[image: git autofetch and git autofetch period settings]

If you shared a settings.json file in your previous role, its possible that that "team" had these enabled, and now the settings.json file you are using in your new role has them disabled.

You may also need to enable `git.pruneOnFetch` as well.

Comment: While I am using my IDE on a Windows vs a Mac now, the GIST hasn't changed. This setting is set to true currently. However, as mentioned in the comment above, git fetch isn't even pulling other branches / hiding deleted ones anyway?

Comment: @DecisiveDevelopment are those perhaps local branches? Those won't get pruned automatically I imagine.  Otherwise, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74320667/new-merged-deleted-branches-not-updating/74320911?noredirect=1#comment131209187_74320667) could be the reason (maybe other members in your repository are using forks instead?).

Comment: Thanks Tim, as you can see in my edit OP the comment above also doesn't seem to work. There isn't forks, that I am aware of. It is a fairly simple repository